# Using Floyd-Warshall algorithm to count number of paths between 2 vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, floyd-warshall

Given an directed unweighted acylic graph, I am trying to adapt Floyd-Warshall algorithm to count the number of paths between 2 vertices. My code currently looks like this:

for all k in 1 to n
     for all i in 1 to n 
       for all j in 1 to n
            Aij = Aij + ( Aik * Akij).

Therefore, instead of checking and replacing for min distance, I am doing the following:

Count of paths between (`i`,`j`) without `k` + ( Count of paths from `i` to `k` * Count of paths from `k` * `j` )

My final array, should have the number of paths between any 2 vertices.

I am not able to prove that this does not give me the count of simple paths between 2 vertices, but there are no suggestions to use this approach elsewhere.

Can someone provide a counter example where this fails?

PS: This is not my homework, but just a programming exercise I picked up.

Comment: `I am not able to prove that this does not give me the count of simple paths between 2 vertices` that means nothing - in order to know for sure if it is correct or not - you should either prove it is working, or find a counter example that shows it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>In an undirected unweighted acylic graph there's at most 1 path between any two vertices. If there were more distinct paths, they would create a cycle.</strike> *(not relevant after question was edited)*

For directed graphs, I don't see a problem with your algorithm. The usage of modified Floyd-Warshall algorithm is actually mentioned in [this paper](http://www.ekt.bme.hu/Cikkek/54-Vattai_Floyd-Warshall_Again.pdf). The reason it's not used widely is probably its complexity - O(n<sup>3</sup>) compared to O(m+n) of [this simple approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164820/1127872)

Comment: I apologize for the typo. I was referring to a directed graph. Corrected the mistake in the original post.

Comment: Great, the paper explains what I needed. I also assumed I could discard the results in the diagonal elements end up being non-zero, as stated in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

In the cyclic graph case, you can't do this with the straight Floyd-Warshall algorithm, because counting simple paths requires you to keep track of where you've been. Dynamic programming assumes that the state being computed is only a function of the states in the recurrence, which is not true in this case.

However, I don't see why this **wouldn't** work. But why use Floyd-Warshall to compute just two verticies (just use a DFS or BFS).

Comment: Yes, I could use DFS/BFS. But, wanted to check the correctness of using Floyd-Warshall. Also, in case of cycles, at the end of computation, I could discard the result if any one of diagonal elements could ending up being a non-zero value. Again, I understand this is not the most efficient.